# Installing CiviCRM on Local: Getting Uncaught Exception Thrown

Tags: drupal

I am beginning to build a new version of our existing Drupal 7 site locally, which has CiviCRM 4.7.15 installed. I installed a fresh copy of the same version of CiviCRM into a fresh SoopterTheme Drupal 7 demo and the installation was successful, however, when I went to review permission settings or click on configuration check list, I get the following error, site-wide. Drupal and CiviCRM both have their own usernames and databases:

> Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception.

I have run through this process multiple times and get the same error. I also received this same error when trying to set up a local copy of the existing site.

If I run any drush commands, I get:

```
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                                                                                       [error]
<p>Initialization Error</p><p><pre>Array
(
    [callback] =&gt; Array
        (
            [0] =&gt; CRM_Core_Error
            [1] =&gt; simpleHandler
        )

    [code] =&gt; -24
    [message] =&gt; DB Error: connect failed
    [mode] =&gt; 16
    [debug_info] =&gt;  [nativecode=No such file or directory]
    [type] =&gt; DB_Error
    [user_info] =&gt;  [nativecode=No such file or directory]
    [to_string] =&gt; [db_error: message=&quot;DB Error: connect failed&quot; code=-24 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::simpleHandler prefix=&quot;&quot; info=&quot; [nativecode=No such file or directory]&quot;]
)
</pre></p><p></p><p>Initialization Error</p><p><pre>Array
(
    [callback] =&gt; Array
        (
            [0] =&gt; CRM_Core_Error
            [1] =&gt; simpleHandler
        )

    [code] =&gt; -24
    [message] =&gt; DB Error: connect failed
    [mode] =&gt; 16
    [debug_info] =&gt;  [nativecode=No such file or directory]
    [type] =&gt; DB_Error
    [user_info] =&gt;  [nativecode=No such file or directory]
    [to_string] =&gt; [db_error: message=&quot;DB Error: connect failed&quot; code=-24 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::simpleHandler prefix=&quot;&quot; info=&quot; [nativecode=No such file or directory]&quot;]
)
</pre></p><p></p>
```

[image: Screenshot of Drupal Site After Installing CiviCRM]

Any guidance is appreciated.

**Edit:** I reinstalled using the same database user for Drupal and CiviCRM and it seemed to have worked initially but I am getting the same error again the next time I went to access the site locally.

Comment: If installed locally, your max_allowed_packet in your .ini file or my.cnf file could be far too low.  Since it's local, I would set it high and forget it.  Something like 100M or 500M should do the trick.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942154/mysql-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away or https://www.drupal.org/node/1014172

Comment: Thanks! I was just reading the MySQL manual and found that. I only set it to 20M but I'm glad to know it can be much higher. It seemed to have done the trick once I restarted the LAMP stack.

Comment: So it's working now?  Hooray!

Comment: This is the correct answer, thanks! I wasn't sure until you confirmed. Much appreciated.

Comment: You're very welcome!

Comment: Funny, I increased my my.conf max_allowed_packet limit to 500M and though I'm not getting the error anymore on the website, I do get the error when I run certain drush commands. Any ideas?

Comment: Are the drush errors the same as in your question above?

Comment: Yes, and it's only certain commands, such as `drush en some_module` which will work even though it throws the error.

Comment: I'm having the above issue again (where it fixed the on-screen error but the initialization error comes up with some drush commands. I vaguely remember fixing something in one of the settings or .htaccess file or something, don't know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If installed locally, your `max_allowed_packet` in your .ini file or my.cnf file could be too low. Since it's local, I would set it high and forget it. Something like 100M or 500M should do the trick. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942154/mysql-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away  or  [drupal.org/node/1014172](http://drupal.org/node/1014172)